# mariaDB client - loading wrong version of openssl

Tags: macos, scala, openssl, mariadb

I am getting some exceptions when I run unit tests. This is the gist of it:

```
12:48:03.412 [Exec Stream Pumper] INFO  ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcess - mysql_install_db: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
12:48:03.412 [Exec Stream Pumper] INFO  ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcess - mysql_install_db:   Referenced from: /private/var/folders/k6/sv2zpx3s6mx170x06z5jwhch0000gn/T/MariaDB4j/base/bin/my_print_defaults
12:48:03.412 [Exec Stream Pumper] INFO  ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcess - mysql_install_db:   Reason: image not found
```

I get the same thing with sbt (just ran `brew update; brew upgrade`) and with intelliJ.

So, on my computer I have this other file: `libssl.1.1.dylib`

I tried asking brew to switch to 1.0.2t or 1.0.2m (if I'm not wrong) but neither worked (I guess they are not available anymore). I even went as far as to symlink the existing ssl/crypto lib files to make it look like the files it uses and then I got errors about missing symbols.

What trick would allow me to move forward?

Update:
In the project's `build.sbt`, we are using

- mariaDB4j             2.4.0
- mariadb-java-client.  2.5.3
- mysql-connector-java. 8.0.11

I updated to mariadb-java-client to `2.7.0` and mysql-connector-java to `8.0.22` but I get the same error with the driver trying to use the old version of libssl.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it.

Following information from https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/635, I ran these commands:

```
brew tap-new $USER/old-openssl
brew extract --version=1.0.2t openssl $USER/old-openssl
brew install openssl@1.0.2t
```

That produced the 2 files that are required in `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0.2t/1.0.2t/lib/` and from there they can be linked into `/usr/local/opt/openssl/li`